# Unable to connect to sql server due to SSL Provider, error: 0

Tags: sql-server

No matter what I try I am not able to connect to one of my SQL Servers. Each time I get the following error:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

I've tried virtually all possible combinations with Integrated Security, User/Password, Persist, Timeout etc. and even only this:

```
<add name="testdb" connectionString="Data Source=mydbserver;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Nothing works. There is however Symantec Endpoint Protection installed on the machine that has the connection issues. It's a Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard

Do you think it might be symantec that blocks connection? Disabling it didn't changed anything either. I have no idea what else I could try.

Both ports 1433 and 1434 are opened (tested with PortQry). I can connect to the testdb from several other machines but not from this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be a firewall rule. Or you have a maximum of logins.

Comment: It turned out it was a firewall problem after all :( because no one knew there were two firewalls inbetween and they adjusted only one of them :|